# MongoDB text search across two collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, full-text-search

I have an Order collection with address fields and User collection with names.  The Order collection contains a string called userId, which is a "foreign key" into the users collection.

I am using an aggregation pipeline to filter, join, sort, and paginate queries.  The problem is that I need to provide full text search on the address and name fields.

Because the $text match must be the first stage in a pipeline, I am not sure how to accomplish the goal of finding text matching any address or name field.

**User collection**

```
[{
    "_id": "5cb8caa069fc1a4351cc3705",
    "firstName": "James",
    "lastName": "Bond"
},{
    "_id": "5c58b8de8596d52c248f34d5",
    "firstName": "Jack",
    "lastName": "Ryan"
}]
```

**Order Collection**

```
[{
    "_id": "5ccc94602e67ca44fe69f160",
    "address": {
        "streetAddress1": "1112 main st",
        "streetAddress2": null,
        "unitNumber": "unit 1112",
        "city": "Jackson Hole",
        "state": "WY",
        "postalCode": "83001"
    },
    "userId": "5cb8caa069fc1a4351cc3705"
}]
```

A search for "Jack" should match both the name "Jack" and the city "Jackson Hole".

Comment: You cannot get what you want with a `$text` search here. The problem being of course that in order to find where the OR condition is either in the address OR the name properties of the user ( i.e "**Jack** Ryan", or "**Jack**son Hole" for James Bond ) you **need** to "join" **before** the search is done, and of course you **cannot do that** since `$text` uses an "index" and must be in the very first aggregation stage, where it cannot be. You can do a `$regex` instead, ***after*** the join. But `$text` could only be used as an AND condition. Before AND after (well "duriing" ) the join.

Comment: Also "to be clear", whilst *possible* using a `$regex` you need to note you **cannot use an index** and this makes the process really inefficient. As such you really should be rethinking your design. Either in 1. Relational joins are really not what MongoDB is "good at". It really prefers "related" information to be "pre joined" by embedding in the same collection. Data  in the same collection can be indexed and an index used for such queries. 2. If the "relational" pattern is important to you, consider a separate dedicated "text search" engine and export data there instead for such searches.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn.  I understand what you are saying, and I think "denormalizing" the names is a possibility, though it presents its own challenges with consistency.  I was wondering if there is a way to join the names from Users into the Orders in a temporary "view," if such a concept exists in MongoDB, and then perform the aggregation pipeline against that instead of the original collections.

Comment: So a "view" is also a **No**. The reason being that "views" in MongoDB are really just "aggregation pipelines" and as such they are not an actual "copy of data" and **cannot** be indexed themselves ( an aggregation pipeline for a view *may* utilize indexes, but only according to the same *first pipeline stage* rules as any other aggregation pipeline). The logical end conclusion *usually* is to denormalize. Yes it does present consistency issues to manage in deference to standard relational practice, but MongoDB is not a relational engine and really should not be used as such.